#  Joomla 2.5.3: MySQL-db: #1064 USING BTREE) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Tags: php, mysql, database, apache, joomla

After a portover of the **joomla version 2.5.3** from a lampp to webserver i have the following trouble: i cannot login to my admin-area: what happened!?

```
500 - An error has occurred.
Return to Control Panel
```

while porting over the db-tables via phpmyadmin all went nice but - suddenly  i got the follwoing error... for the user table...

MySQL says ,,, [and i guess that it was told with a prefix - a preliminary notice that told me that the users-table was not ported over due to some errors... (guessing that the local and the "web-server-database are not 100 % simmilar and equvialent... What do you say!?
But - besides this - if you have a closer look at the number of tables then we see that there are tables missing... that is the important thing .... i cant help myself - there are several tables missiing.!!

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=9' at line 17
```

so then i have to do the portover of the users-table manually. but as i see now - there are more tables missing. approximatly 5  to seven tables were missing and - as mentioned above - i was not able to login

```
500 - An error has occurred.
Return to Control Panel
```

Some  findings: Some friends told me that this has to do with the compliance of the dbs - the local db is not like the db at the  webserver.

So i decided to reupload the complete db-stucture of the user-area .. that ar 5 to 7 [!?] tables, arent they!? So now i need to have some tables of the neweset joomla-version - i need the complete tables - everything that has to do with the "user" out of the joomla-version 2.5.4

Guess that these are the following tables:

```
oqlgu_user_notes    
oqlgu_user_profiles     
oqlgu_user_usergroup_map    
oqlgu_usergroups
oqlgu_users
```

**Two questions:** are these all the tables that i need? Can you tell me where to get them!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do your MySQL database versions match? You need to use the same version of MySQL on both machines or adjust the SQL to match the version on the production server.

> Before MySQL 5.0.60, this option can be given only before the ON
>   tbl_name clause. Use of the option in this position is deprecated as
>   of 5.0.60 and support for it there will be removed in a future MySQL
>   release. If an index_type option is given in both the earlier and
>   later positions, the final option applies.
>
> TYPE type_name is recognized as a synonym for USING type_name.
>   However, USING is the preferred form.

Comment: Hello dear Burhan Khalid many thanks for the answer. I try apply all your advices. I come back later and report all my findings. Untill later the day.